# Embedded Jetty org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog not working

Tags: json, logging, cross-domain, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty using Jersey Moxy JSON support to provide JSON contracts. It works on the @GET but not on the one @PUT I have (never gets hit) I also have the cross origin filter configured in web.xml, but it is not working, like to see some log output for the class that loads that.

So I need logging and have implemented according to this  https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html and the following 2 pages in the documentation.

So I have a jetty-logging.properties that has this content on the classpath (in src/main/path to main class) and I checked it is in the target directory too. I note " loadProperties("jetty-logging.properties",__props);" and the statement "This is an optional feature used by embedded mode use" in org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.java, so it should get picked up.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.LEVEL=DEBUG
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.LEVEL=ALL
```

I have implemented the request log as per the documentation and that it is run at runtime, here it is:

```
    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{contexts,new DefaultHandler(),requestLogHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog(locn);
    requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
    requestLog.setAppend(true);
    requestLog.setExtended(false);
    requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
    requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```

I  tried both relative paths and full Windows paths (using /) for the locn variable.

I tried setting up Eclipse debug parameter like so as an alternate:
    -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
    -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.servlet.LEVEL=ALL

At no point do I get a log file. What am I missing? Documentation of course does not refer to embedded Jetty, and I have chased lots of different articles on how it should work, but not found anything that solves my problem.

Edit:
I note from mvn dependency:tree output I get:

```
+- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
 |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:test
 |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
```

And in console i get:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Could this be upsetting jetty's use of StdErrLog?

Answer (score 0):

To get the logs working I had to realise that the setHandler(Handler) and setHandler(Handler[]) will overwrite each other. I had the former in my setupLogging method seen above and the latter in my main method and it ran after the setupLogging method thus overwriting the RequestLogHandler with the other handlers and filters I had.